# does remove an applied migration automatically modify database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm new to EF, just a question on remove/delete already applied migration.

I always thought removing an applied migration cause out of sync in database, but I found it  automatically modify database too. Below is my code:

firstly, I have a Product class:

```
public class Product
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

then I created an initial migration and updated to it

> dotnet ef migrations add Initial
>
> dotnet ef database update

then I added a new property `InStock` to the Product class and then issued commands

> dotnet ef migrations add AddInStock
>
> dotnet ef database update

then I tried to remove this applied migration by

> dotnet ef migrations remove --force

the CLI window showed logging message and I saw `Alter Table[Product] Drop Column [InStock]`, which means the "InStock" column has been dropped.

If that was the case, why I always heard that "Remove an applied migration will cause out of sync problem in database"? in my case, the database gets updated with the removal of applied migration, it is always in sync with the project.

another question is, the code above is from  a textbook and I follow it to learn, the textbook says when issue a force remove, there will be following logging message :

```
Removing migration '<timestamp>_AddInStock' without checking the database. If this
migration has been applied to the database, you will need to manually reverse the changes
it made.
Removing migration '<timestamp>_AddInStock'.
Reverting model snapshot.
```

but how come I didn't have this message when issue `dotnet ef migrations remove --force`?

Answer (score 1):

`dotnet ef migrations remove` won't normally modify your database, but since you're using the `--force` option, it will.

If you didn't specify `--force`, you would have had to use `dotnet ef database update` to rollback your database to a previous migration before calling `remove`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-migrations-remove

Comment: if rollback to previous migration and then call remove, of course there won't be any out of sync problems. so what's the command thatcan cause out of sync database problem?

Comment: Not using the `--force` switch with `dotnet ef migrations remove` can cause a sync problem, because it removes the Migration without rolling back changes to the database.

Comment: but I couldn't remove the applied migration by `dotnet ef migrations remove` without `--force`, there is a error message says: The migration '<timestamp>_AddInStock'  has already been applied to the database, revert it and try again, so how can  I create out of sync this time?

Comment: I'm confused again, I might have wrong description in my post. Now I think `dotnet ef migrations remove --force` will cause an out of sync problem, because there is no "InStock" column in the database, but in the application  "InStock" property still exist in the .cs file,that's how out of sync occurs, isn't it?